# sed, comma, dollar sign, single quote and double quote

Tags: regex, linux, shell, unix, sed

The question is complex, but I hope the answer will be simple and just because I've overlook something.

What I'm trying to do is, I'm trying to use "sed" command to get all lines since a matched line, from a file.

I figure out the following commands works for my purpose:

```
sed -n '/\[ ocsp \]/,$p' openssl.cnf
```

However, I'd like to have the matching word passed in as a variable. Therefore, I'll need to change the quote from single quote to double quote.

It DOES NOT WORK as I expected!

My understanding is that, the comma and dollar sign tell s the sed command to print from the matched point until the end of file. I didn't see anything funny here. However, after I change to double quote, I get error message like:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unexpected `,'
```

and I tried escape or put the command after matching pattern in to {} sign etc. Nothing works.

Need some help out here, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside double quotes bash expands `$var` to the value of `var`. Inside single quotes bash doesn't interpret a dollar sign in this way. So if you changed quotes, than `$p` was expanded to (probably) empty value and yelded an error. Just add single baskslash before last `$`.

```
sed -n "/\\[ ocsp \\]/,\$p" openssl.cnf
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer. I remember that I've tried it and doesn't work, but I must have made some other mistake also and it works now. So, thank you again!